# application deploys but does not load, console log showcases an error

Tags: javascript, ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to deploy my application but an error keeps stopping the initialization, I have tried some solutions but none has worked
link to the repo for codes - https://github.com/Demiladekusa/Evoting-dapp

this is the error I keep getting
[image]

I am trying to connect to the local host to interact with the application, the application gets stuck on loading

any help with the issue is appreciated, thank you !

Comment: That's not a JavaScript error but rather some of your libraries aren't functioning properly, without any context and code we can't guess what's going on

Comment: And are you saying that it works fine in your localhost but not once deployed? I have to guess have you provided environment variables?

Answer (score 1):

That error indicates that you are on the wrong network.

with this config, you are deploying the contract to ganache

```
networks: {
        development: {
            host: "127.0.0.1",
            port: 7545,
            network_id: "*", // Match any network id
        },
    },
```

In order to interact with the contract,you have to connect with the ganache network. so you have to add ganache network to metamask.

[Please follow this guide](https://docs.cranq.io/web-3/setting-up-ganache-with-metamask) to add ganache network to metamask. After that you connect to Ganache named (you can name anything) network on metamask. then it should work.

Comment: hey thanks for the response, tried the configuration file it didn’t necessarily work.

what I'm working on is quite similar to this repository- https://github.com/parv3213/Election-Dapp

please do you mind sparing time to clone the repo and try for running it yourself and see the outcome

Comment: did you signup for ingura keys. that should work